# alsa snd_pcm_writei synchronization

Tags: synchronization, alsa

Hello I'm developing a sound player using the alsa's API and using the snd_pcm_writei.

In CENTOS5 and alsa 1.0.18RC3 works ok, but over Ubuntu 10.10 and alsa 1.0.23, I have a problem with the timing.

I set a buffer size and period size of 40ms. In CENTOS5, snd_pcm_writei blocked me 40ms, that's ok, but in Ubuntu, snd_pcm_writei blocked me 80ms and then no blocked me in the next call, then 80ms then 0....but why? I each call I write 40 ms, It's as if the buffer size is 80ms and the sound card  need another 40ms to fill the buffer and then wait 80ms until the frames are played, but I set 40ms in buffer size and I check it.

So my question is, what can I do for have 40ms between calls?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you post the output of snd_pcm_hw_params_dump for each machine?

Comment: Hello waffeman, I changed I little bit my hw configuration, I set 40ms for a period size and 80 ms for a buffer size, the result is the same

Comment: UBUNTU:                                                             ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED/
FORMAT:  S16_LE/
SUBFORMAT:  STD/
SAMPLE_BITS: 16/
FRAME_BITS: 32/
CHANNELS: 2/
RATE: 48000
PERIOD_TIME: 40000/
PERIOD_SIZE: 1920/
PERIOD_BYTES: 7680/
PERIODS: 2/
BUFFER_TIME: 80000/
BUFFER_SIZE: 3840/
BUFFER_BYTES: 15360/
TICK_TIME: ALL/

Comment: CENTOS: ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED//
FORMAT:  S16_LE/
SUBFORMAT:  STD/
SAMPLE_BITS: 16/
FRAME_BITS: 32/
CHANNELS: 2/
RATE: 48000/
PERIOD_TIME: 40000/
PERIOD_SIZE: 1920/
PERIOD_BYTES: 7680/
PERIODS: 2/
BUFFER_TIME: 80000/
BUFFER_SIZE: 3840/
BUFFER_BYTES: 15360/
TICK_TIME: 1000/